# pyautoGUI didnt work for some lines (Access Client Solutions)

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

the python script is working but skipping few lines for no reasons. this is for automation application, (Access Client Solutions).

Regarding ACS login, I have observed that it requires two login attempts. The first attempt is successful, but the second attempt fails due to the script skipping the injection lines while executing the "Tab" and "Enter" commands. It is noteworthy that this double login feature was functional in the previous SIT Environment. Additionally, the lines of code for the first and second login attempts are identical. Therefore, it is unclear why this part is being skipped??

```
print("Injection Starting")
    try:
        ky.send_keys(username)
        time.sleep(2)
        ky.send_keys("{TAB}") 
        ky.send_keys(password)
        time.sleep(2)
        ky.send_keys("{ENTER}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during first injection: {str(e)}") #f-string with expression with {}.

    print("Second Injection Starting")
    try:
        ky.send_keys(username)    #somehow this is being skipped.
        time.sleep(3)
        ky.send_keys("{TAB}")     #but this part it worked.
        ky.send_keys(password)    #again, this is being skipped.
        time.sleep(3)
        ky.send_keys("{ENTER}")   #and this part it worked.
        time.sleep(3)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during second injection: {str(e)}")
```

Has anyone encounter this problem?
My next attempt, probably I'll replace it with pyautoGUI but I highly doubts it will work.
Strange.

Thats all. Thank you!